# Stripe Checkout: Using saved Source vs a new token to create a Charge

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

I'm using Stripe Checkout. In all the documentation I can find, Stripe recommends saving `Customer` information (including a default `Source`) during my first transaction with that customer, and using that default `Source` later when I want to create subsequent `Charge`s. However, if a customer uses a different credit card during a subsequent Checkout transaction, it would be a mistake to charge the default `Source`.

So, it seems like I should always just use the token from stripe.js when making subsequent changes, and that I should create a new source for the customer whenever I detect the them using a card that's different from the default source.

However, in my testing it appears as though every token I get from stripe.js represents a unique card, even if I've used the same credit card number, expiration, and CVC. If I were to create a new card for each Checkout token and save it to the customer record, I'd potentially end up with mounds of duplicate card records for each customer.

Am I overlooking a way to associate stripe.js tokens with customers in a way that doesn't generate duplicates? Or am I going about this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you collect card details in Checkout, Stripe will create a new token for that card even if they use the same card details. The [Token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object) resource has the `fingerprint` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object-card-fingerprint) though.

That property is a unique identifier for a given card number in your account. This means that if I sign up today with my card and then I come back tomorrow with the same card under a different email address you'd see the same exact fingerprint on both Token or Card objects. The idea then would be to keep track of all the card fingerprints you see in your database to detect a returning customer. Whenever a customer adds a new card you'd first look if you've seen that card fingerprint before in your database and decide to create the customer or return an error based on this.

Separately, you should not offer Checkout for a customer that already has a saved card. Instead you should show them the card(s) available for example by showing the card brand and last 4 digits. And then the customer can either pay with one of those cards or add a new one.

You can add more than one card to a customer or replace the default one. You can also decide which card to charge by passing both the customer id in `customer` and the card id in `source`. This is all covered in details in Stripe's documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards).

Comment: "Separately, you should not offer Checkout for a customer that already has a saved card. Instead you should show them the card(s) available for example by showing the card brand and last 4 digits. And then the customer can either pay with one of those cards or add a new one."


Ah, I hadn't gotten this point, but it makes a lot of sense. Thank you!